# PHP put null if value not sent to public function

Tags: php, class, function, variables, public

I thought this would be easy, but some reason it is not work

```
public function test($data = null){

}
```

but when I want to send some data to the function it turns it to null so how can i have it so that if i dont send anything it is null otherwise it the data I sent

Comment: No way this could happen. http://codepad.org/m0wkMrSz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function test($data = null){
     echo $data;
}

test('abcd'); // output abcd
```

see working example http://codepad.viper-7.com/Z8T23k

Answer (score 0):

that looks about right for optional parameter syntax. We'll have to have more details to tell you what is not working